# How transform a recursive void function into a recursive function that returns a result on linked list

Tags: c

Compare the elements of a linked list in pairs, each time choosing the minimum of the two and placing it in another linked list result.

Example: we have a list [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] the output must be a sublist such as [1, 3, 5] since min(1,2) = 1 and min(3,4) =3 and min(5,6)=5.

Here's the recursive function I've written.

How transform a recursive void function into a recursive function that returns a result on linked list (return head_dest).
Can we simplify this recursive function (I find it a little complicated, but it works) and how can we transform this void recursive function into a recursive function that returns a result on the linked list?

```
/* Function to get the nth node from the last of a linked list*/
void pairWiseMinimumInNewList_Rec(Node* head, Node* cur_list_dest, Node** head_dest)
{   
    /* There must be at-least two nodes in the list */
    if (head != NULL && head->pt_next != NULL) 
    { 
        /* Treatement */
        if (head->val < head->pt_next->val) 
          {
            if (*head_dest==NULL)   //if (!head_dest)
               { 
                *head_dest=head;
                cur_list_dest=head;
               }
             else
               { 
                cur_list_dest->pt_next=head;
                cur_list_dest=head;
               } 
          }
        else
            {
             if (!*head_dest) 
               { 
                *head_dest=head->pt_next;
                cur_list_dest=head->pt_next;
               }
             else
               {
                cur_list_dest->pt_next=head->pt_next;
                cur_list_dest=head->pt_next;

               } 
            }

        /* Call pairWiseMinimumInNewList() for the rest of the list */
        pairWiseMinimumInNewList_Rec(head->pt_next->pt_next, cur_list_dest, head_dest);         
    }

   else if (head)    
       {
         if (*head_dest==NULL) 
            { 
               *head_dest=head;

            }
         else //Treatment of the last node if the linked list contains an odd (impair) number of nodes
            { 
            cur_list_dest->pt_next=head;

            }
       }            
     else  // if (!head && ! head->pt_next)
          { //mark end on the last node of the new linked list if the linked list contains an even (pair) number of nodes
            cur_list_dest->pt_next=NULL;                        
          }
}

In the main()
Node* head_dest=NULL; Node* cur_list_dest=NULL;
pairWiseMinimumInNewList_Rec(head, NULL, &head_dest);
```

Comment: Please post something one could compile and test. Unless this is an exercise I see no use for recursion here. And a bit of encapsulation would help a lot. There not even a `List` here and this leads to a number of global loose pointers...

Comment: You've got some intense `if/else` ladders. Including `else if (head) if (*head_dest == NULL) *head_dest = NULL else { }` I'd add some _explicit_ `{}` pairs to ensure that the correct `else` is paired with the correct `if`

Comment: What if the original list has an odd number of elements?

Comment: Post code  you compiled and tested not psudo code (i.e. "In the main()").  Definition of `Node` is missing.  `head` is not defined in `main()`.

Comment: You current implementation changes the original list.  In other words `head` and `head_dest` contain the same list (not a new list), and all the max nodes are leaked.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Is writing a recursive function a requirement? Far easier to iterate a pointer-to-pointer. See [Linus on Understanding Pointers](https://grisha.org/blog/2013/04/02/linus-on-understanding-pointers/). Then simply change the return type to return a pointer-to-node. (As @AllanWind suggests in his answer)

Comment: Prefer iterative to recursive algorithms in C.  C doesn't guarantee tail call optimization which means each recursive call may generate a stack frame.  If the problem is sufficiently large your program will segfault when it runs out of stack space.

Answer (score 1):

1. Return a pointer to the `Node` of interest instead of updating the out parameter `head_dest`.  The stack will implicitly hold `cur_list_dest`.
2. The original implementation changes the original list.  To create a new list you need to return a pointer to *copy* of the smallest node or NULL.  To emphasize that I made the argument constant with `const Node *head`.
3. Observe that `pairWiseMinimumInNewList_Rec()` either returns a copy of 1st node, 2nd node or NULL (3 values).  The recursive call is either two nodes head or NULL (2 values).  For at most 6 cases.  If you make the values conditional instead of expressions you can collapse that into a single return statement.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int val;
    struct Node *pt_next;
} Node;

Node *linked_list_new(int val, Node *pt_next) {
    Node *n = malloc(sizeof *n);
    if(!n) {
        printf("malloc failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    n->val = val;
    n->pt_next = pt_next;
    return n;
}

Node *linked_list_create(size_t n, int *vals) {
    Node *head = NULL;
    Node **cur = &head;
    for(size_t i=0; i < n; i++) {
        *cur = linked_list_new(vals[i], NULL);
        if(!head) head = *cur;
        cur = &(*cur)->pt_next;
    }
    return head;
}

void linked_list_print(Node *head) {
    for(; head; head=head->pt_next)
        printf("%d->", head->val);
    printf("NULL\n");
}

void linked_list_free(Node *head) {
    while(head) {
        Node *tmp = head->pt_next;
        free(head);
        head=tmp;
    }
}

Node *pairWiseMinimumInNewList_Rec(const Node* head) {
    return head ?
        linked_list_new(
            (head->pt_next && head->val < head->pt_next->val) || !head->pt_next ?
            head->val :
            head->pt_next->val,
            pairWiseMinimumInNewList_Rec(head->pt_next ? head->pt_next->pt_next : NULL)
        ) :
        NULL;
}

int main() {
    Node *head=linked_list_create(7, (int []) {2,1,3,4,5,6,7});
    Node* head_dest=pairWiseMinimumInNewList_Rec(head);
    linked_list_free(head);
    linked_list_print(head_dest);
    linked_list_free(head_dest);
}
```

Example run of a test case that exercises more of the code paths than what was given:

```
1->3->5->7->NULL
```

Comment: Hi,
Thank you very much Allan and hats off to you, that's impressive.
Your solution is a few different. In your opinion, is it necessary to create a new list (linked_list_new()) because in my solution I only wanted to retrieve the head (address of the first or second element) of the new list usiing recursion.